# Get a subset of a dataframe where columns must contain substring (if not, ignore those rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are a lot of questions similar to this, but none asking this specific question, and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Assume I have a dataframe `df` that looks like the one shown below, and assume each column can have other substrings (though, the substrings shown below are all unique to one column per row, eg if one column has 'Coin' in it, no other other column in that row can contain the substring 'Coin').

This example shows whole strings, but assume that a row with 'Coin' in it could actually be 'Coin (quarters)', such that it must search out the substring 'Coin' and not assume 'Coin' is the whole string.

```
>>> df

   1       2       3       4       cap
0  Coin    Bill    Charge          72
1  Coin                            13
2  Charge  Coin                     1
3  Bill    Other   Coin    Charge  57
4  Charge  Bill                    11
5  Coin    Charge                   8
6  Other   Bill    Charge   Coin   99
7  Charge                          45 
8  Charge  Coin                    15
9  Bill    Other   Coin            71
```

What I want to do is select rows if and only if columns contain 'Coin' and 'Charge' but none of the other unique substrings. Essentially, if and only if a column contains 'Coin' and a column contains 'Charge' and the rest of the columns DO NOT contain 'Bill' or 'Other' or they have an empty string.

So in the example above, the resulting dataframe would be a subset of `df`:

```
>>> df_res

   1       2       3       4       cap
2  Charge  Coin                     1
5  Coin    Charge                   8
8  Charge  Coin                    15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df[
    df.apply(
        lambda x: "Coin" in (v := x.values)
        and "Charge" in v
        and "Bill" not in v
        and "Other" not in v,
        axis=1,
    )
]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
        1       2 3 4  cap
2  Charge    Coin        1
5    Coin  Charge        8
8  Charge    Coin       15
```

---

EDIT: To search substrings:

```py
x = df[
    df.apply(
        lambda x: any("Coin" in i for i in x if isinstance(i, str))
        and any("Charge" in i for i in x if isinstance(i, str))
        and not any("Bill" in i for i in x if isinstance(i, str))
        and not any("Other" in i for i in x if isinstance(i, str)),
        axis=1,
    )
]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
        1               2 3 4  cap
2  Charge  Coin(quarters)        1
5    Coin          Charge        8
8  Charge            Coin       15
```

Comment: `df.apply` is super slow :/

Comment: @JoranBeasley After all, the values are strings. Pandas won't help much here, it's geared towards numeric processing.

Comment: a str.join and a str.search might be faster ... although ultimately this should work so ...

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't work if "Coin" or "Charge" is a substring in a larger string. Only if they are on their own.